# Writing to a file column by column C++

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

i'm struggling to find a way to this and can't seem to find any solution anywhere, but I imagine it has to be possible.

I would like to write to a file, column by column instead of row by row.I have an arrays of strings which get updated as my program is running. The strings look like this "--4---" , "1-----", "--15---", "----6-" etc.

These need to be written to a file aligned column by column, from left to right. eg. :

```
--1-------
----------
4----15---
----------
-------6--
----------
```

I am using ofstream. I could wait until a certain number of strings are updated, then print them row by row to the file, but it gets messy when I have numbers with two digits , as have to correct offsets in advance (each array index must be aligned) etc.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Really hard to do this with text because you won't know where to put the line feed until you have the whole row and by then the point is kind of moot. I don't suppose you can write the file with columns as rows and then instruct the user to turn their monitor sideways?

Comment: Files don't have a notion of columns or rows. A file is just a stream of bytes. What you normally call a row is just a part of a file between two `\n` characters. If you look at it like that you will see that this cannot be done directly, because what would a column be? On the other hand if you can define it (for example by fixing each rows and each cells length) then it becomes possible by preallocating each row in advance. So it all comes to one thing: what does "column" mean to you?

Comment: seems like an XY problem, files really don't know what a "column" or a "row" is. But this "when I have numbers with two digits" part kinda hints that you may want to try binary files instead of writing text

Comment: The problem would come if you don't know how many rows there will be ahead of time, because you won't know how much space to leave. One solution would be to write each column to it's own file. Or just write the rows to a file, and write the input code to get columns from that file. Basically there's no way to properly create the desired file until you know how many rows there will be.

Comment: Do you know from the start how many columns and rows, you'll have in the end?

Comment: not really , it will be dynamic. As the program is running, the strings in the array will be updated. Yes, it's not a straight forward problem to solve

Answer (score 2):

A better method is to model the file in memory, then write the memory to the file.

If your text representation has 5 columns, I recommend using a matrix with 6 columns and let the 6th column be a newline.

```
#define MAX_ROWS 4
#define MAX_COLUMNS (5+1)

char board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];

// Initialize the board
for (size_t row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++row)
{
  for (size_t column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS - 1; ++column)
  {
    board[row][column] = '-';
  }
  board[row][column] = '\n';
}
board[MAX_ROWS-1][MAX_COLUMNS-1] = '\0'; // Add terminating NULL.
```

You can then print the board by:

```
cout << (char *)(&board[0][0]) << endl;
```

Usually, writing to memory is a lot faster than writing to a file.  Also, you can output the *board* in any format, such as CSV or XML.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will check it out

Comment: This is something similar to what I was doing already. It still doesn't solve the problem of when I need to print 2 digits tho and maintain alignment